# Pivot chart losing format after refresh

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I have hundreds of pivot charts and every time i refresh the data i keep losing my data labels on the charts. I'm interested if it's possible to not lose the data labels or for a way to apply my chart formatting on all my charts in the worksheet.

Comment: If possible, could you provide a sample file about your problem?